# TreeView NodeMouseClick - How to tell what part of node clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a TreeView and ShowPlusMinus is set to true.  I also want the nodes (parents only) to Toggle when the Text is single clicked.  Here is my NodeMouseClick event handler:

```
    private void NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.GetNodeCount(true) == 0)
        {
            if (MapClick != null) MapClick(this, e); // fire an event that a child was clicked
        }
        else
        {
            e.Node.Toggle();
        }
    }
```

I can't use AfterSelect because I need to toggle even if the node is already selected.

The problem with NodeMouseClick is that it is also called when the user clicks the plus/minus icon.  So the node toggles twice.  I need to either prevent the default behavior and always do the Toggle myself, or I need to detect where the item is clicked and only do the toggle when it is not on the plus/minus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the TreeView.HitTest() method to discover what part was clicked.  Something like this (omitting your logic because I can't make sense of it):

```
    private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
        var hit = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);
        if (hit.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.Label) {
            // etc..
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about HitTest.  Yeah, basically the logic is to toggle the node if it's a parent node (folder hierarchy), or fire an event if it's a child node (the actual "map document").  I'll try HitTest.  I'm sure that will work!